# Non-empty object returns <<empty string>>

Tags: javascript, pug

I had to call a javascript function in jade and pass a span value to this function, but span value return empty text.

```
section.main.taskboard
    .taskboard-header
        h1
            span.green.sdate(tg-bo-bind="startdate") 
script.
     var vsdate = document.getElementsByClassName('sdate')[0];
     console.log(vsdate);
     console.log(vsdate.innerText);
```

returns :

```
     <span class="green sdate" tg-bo-bind="sprint.estimated_start">
     <<empty string>>
```

Comment: What else did you expect instead?

Comment: value of span . The value (InnerText) of this span is "2021-07-11"

Comment: no it's not. at least not at the time the javascript runs